# BackgroundWorker DoWork Async "Not Work" with Bluetoothfunction C++

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2012, backgroundworker

I have written an algorithm for Scanning Bluetooth-Devices and add it in my listbox.Now I want that this algorithm runinng permanently in the background. But my Backgroundworker doesn't work correctly. Even my UI is also unresponisve.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         toolStripStatusLabel1->Text="Active";
         toolStripProgressBar1->Value=100;
         backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
     }

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
         BluetoothFunction(); \\It tells me here is an Error
     }

void BluetoothFunction(){
        m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);

        do{
            vector<wstring> vec;
            int m_device_id=0;
            int m_radio_id = 0;
            m_radio_id++;
            BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);

            m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
            ::ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
            m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
            m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);

            do{
                wostringstream tmp;
                ++m_device_id;

                //Konvertiere Byte in String
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                  tmp << hex << m_device_info.Address.rgBytes [i];
                  if (i < 5)
                    tmp << L':';
                }                   

                //Verfügbarkeitsliste
                vec.push_back(tmp.str());

                listBox2->Items->Add(System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringUni(IntPtr((void*) tmp.str().c_str())));

            }while(BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));
            //searchId(vec, targetId); 
            BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev);

        } while(BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));
        BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt);      
}
```

I guess that my parameters for the Bluetoothfunction is not correct.

I would be glad about it, if somebody can help me.

Regards